# Chess Rails app with low latency possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, latency

Is a low latency chess app possible with Rails? The Rails framework is mainly geared towards being stateless afaik.

One approach to implementing chess in Rails would be given a move (the "request"), read the current position from the database, check that the move is valid in the current position and compute the new position, write that new position to the database, and send it to the other player.

This has the advantage of being stateless as nothing is maintained in memory between requests. But it involves fetching the current position from the database every time. And presumably this will be a significant hit on latency.

Suppose instead the positions of the games are maintained in memory. A move updates that in-memory position and sends a response to the other player. After which the database is updated. If the games are sharded over many Unicorn/Thin/Mongrel processes, how would requests be routed to the correct Unicorn process for that game. Do I need some kind of routing process inbetween my Nginx/Lighty/Apache process and my Unicorn/Thin/Mongrel processes that has a table that maps games to their correct Unicorn shard?

This type of problem strikes me as something that many others must have encountered. Is there an idiomatic way to do this in Rails?

Comment: I do not think that storing game state in RAM is a good idea - without persistence offered by dbms your data can be lost at any time... Why do you think fetching game state from db will give low latency?

Comment: I meant to imply that after updating game state in RAM the database is updated as well. I edited my post to add that in.

Comment: For me it seems like db latency will not be the problem for such application. If you want asynchronous db operations - so you'd better look at [EventMachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine) or [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) + websockets protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you store all of this in a message queue like RabbitMQ or Redis? Message queues are persistant and performant. This Railscast uses beanstalkd (a different message queue) to introduce a very similar app to yours: http://railscasts.com/episodes/243-beanstalkd-and-stalker